# Patching bean config XML file dynamically using sed?

Tags: xml, regex, replace, sed

I have a bean configuration XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>MyDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>#####</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>myUser</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>myPassword</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I want to replace the string `#####` dynamically with sed.

`#####` may have different values, e.g. `myUrl1`, `myUrl2` etc. and should be replaced with another given `myUrlX`

So the result should be something like:

```
        ...
        <property name="url">
            <value>myUrlX</value>
        </property>
        ...
```

So far I only got close to a solution with the following sed command:

```
sed -n "1h;1!H;${;g;s|\(<property [^>]*>.*<value>\).*\(</value>.*</property>\)|\1myUrl\2|g;p;}" test.xml
```

But this replaces the `myPassword` string in my XML file instead of `#####`.

Could anyone give me a hint what I need to change in my sed command?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xml ed --update "/beans/bean[@id='myDataSource']/property[@name='url']/value" --value myUrlX inputfile.xml
```

To query:

```
xml sel -t -m "/beans/bean[@id='myDataSource']/property[@name='url']" -v value inputfile.xml
```

Put them together:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=inputfile.xml
val=$(xml sel -t -m "/beans/bean[@id='myDataSource']/property[@name='url']" -v value "$file")
if [[ $val == "foo" ]]
then
    val=bar
    xml ed --update "/beans/bean[@id='myDataSource']/property[@name='url']/value" --value "$val" "$file"
fi
```

On my system, the command is `xmlstarlet` instead of `xml`.

[Don't use regexes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Peter: I'm glad I was able to help. Since you found the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted.